# Creating city, county, state relations

Tags: sql-server, relation

I downloaded this csv file from [here](http://www.populardata.com/zipcode_database.html) it contains the following:

Database columns:

```
ZIP
LATITUDE
LONGITUDE
CITY
STATE
COUNTY
ZIP_CLASS
```

Now I imported this into SQL Server, and I have a table with the same columns. From that table I created a `states` and `county` tables like so:

**States**:

```
insert into states(name)
select distinct [state] from newlist order by state asc
```

**Counties**:

```
insert into counties(name, stateid)
select distinct n.[county], s.id as stateid
from newlist n
inner join states s on n.[state] = s.name
order by county asc
```

Now when I want to create a `cities` table and have a relation to the county id I keep getting way to many duplicates

`Cities`:

```
select distinct n.[city], c.id as countyid
from newlist n
inner join counties c on n.[county] = c.name
order by city asc
```

Original table has about 30,000 records and when running that it gives me over 140,000 records. What I see is it has to do with the county being in different states? If needed I can attach the SQL script with the table structure and data if that makes it easier to help me out with this. Really stuck and not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are like 10 states with an "Orange County."   Is the state in the county table coming from your source data, or are you inferring it by name?

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Counties(name, stateid)
  SELECT DISTINCT LIST.name LIST.stateid
  FROM NewList  LIST
```

and then

```
 INSERT INTO Cities(city, countyid)
  SELECT DISTINCT LIST.city, COUNTY.countyid
    FROM NewList LIST
         INNER JOIN Counties COUNTY
            ON COUNTY.state = LIST.stateid
            AND COUNTY.name = LIST.county
```

This presumes that the stateid is the two-character state code

Comment: because the original data did not come with ID's the I have to use the name.  I think thats where its throwing me off when trying to get cities

Comment: this list includes zip codes but im not using them right now, how would that resolve it? not quite sure what u mean

Comment: when storing county or state ID its actually an integer and no longer text, let me give this a shot but just wanted to let u know

Comment: That's the issue:  especially if  you're using Y_M for the "between" operation.   if  you select the range '1212 to 1213', that will automatically exclude '0313' (which is actually 313).   If you were to redefine the Y_M column to include the FULL year (e.g. 201203), it will work, and will not be any less performant.   Better still, your database will work consistently around century and millenium boundaries.